# route not defined error even after changing default route in the unauthenticated method using laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this is the handler class and i have override the method for guest

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception){
        return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                    : redirect()->guest(route('admin'));
    }
```

my routes file has these routes that i want to reach

```
Route::get('admin','Admin\AdminController@createAdminform');
Route::post('admin','Admin\AdminController@adminLogin');
```

Comment: Did you clear the route cache ? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Route::get('admin','Admin\AdminController@createAdminform')->name('admin');

Comment: Add the name method to the route

Comment: but does'nt that 'admin' in the start of the route specify the route name?

Comment: thanks @DevinGray giving the name solved my problem. Can you tell me also that as i am new to laravel does'nt that 'admin' in the start of the route specify the route name?

Comment: Not explicitly, basically what you were doing was calling an undefined route with the name "admin", until you tell the application what your routes name is, you cannot call it in that way. You could however have said `redirect('/admin')`, the only issue is that you used the route() helper, so that looks for a name

Comment: yep got your point thanks @DevinGray for help :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your route like below:-
`Route::get('admin','Admin\AdminController@createAdminform')->name('admin');`

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing)

Named Routes

Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes. You may specify a name for a route by chaining the name method onto the route definition:

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
//
})->name('profile');
```

You may also specify route names for controller actions:

`Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');`

For more understanding I suggest you go through the official Routing documentation of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are calling a named route using the `route()` helper function in Laravel. In the docs

```
$url = route('routeName');
```

The route function generates a URL for the given named route:

The keywords there are `named routes`

Which explains why `Route::get('admin','Admin\AdminController@createAdminform');` is not equal to `redirect()->guest(route('admin'));`

until you give your route a name, using the named routes functionality, Laravel will not know what route you are looking to use, so the `route()` function will throw an undefined exception.

So here are some ways that you can get around this.

The correct way is to add an override function to the `app/Exceptions/Handler` file that looks like this

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('/admin');
}
```

If you really want to use named routes, you would keep the above, and tweak it to use those routes, however, it should remain consistent, if you use named routes here, use them everywhere.

Change the route to look like this

`Route::get('admin','Admin\AdminController@createAdminform')->name('admin');`

and then alter the unauthenticated function we just created

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('admin));
}
```

Personally, unless I am using named routes elsewhere, and it makes sense to keep the route names in a constant like this, I think it is easier to just add the 'admin' string to get what you want.

I know most of this was answered by @parthu_panther in the above answer, just adding my answer as my comment solved the question